# .Net / SQL Server: Compare dates (datetime<->datetime, datetime<->varchar)

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have two issues in two project, both are related to datetime.

**Project 1**:

Date is saved as `yyyy/MM/dd` in SQL Server 2008 database, but `System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` returns `dd/MM/yyyy`. The SQL query written as inline code fails to compare both dates. I have tried `ParseExact`, `CAST`, `Convert` and many other options but couldn't get it to work.

**Project 2**:

In SQL Server 2008 database, datetime is saved in a `varchar(50)` column. Using the `Between` clause fails from inline SQL query even after trying a lot of options.

Note: I am using express editions on front end and back end.

Please help in both. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're storing a date&time, ***DO NOT*** use `varchar(50)` !! Plain and simple. Use an **appropriate** datatype - either `DATE` if you need only the date (no time), or `DATETIME2(n)` if you need both date and time portions.

Comment: "In SQL Server 2008 database, datetime is saved in a varchar(50) column." - why on earth would you? seriously.

Answer (score -1):

With any DateTime in .NET, you can provide the datetime format in the tostring function. With this, you can force your Datetime to be formatted the same as SQL Server for comparison.

Comment: You should **NOT** convert date/time to a **string** to compare - you should leave them as **native `DATETIME`** types and compare those! (because those are **independent** of any formatting and other crap!)

Answer (score -1):

**Project 1: solution**

you can convert the date as below format it simple :

```
select convert(varchar,dateadd(MI, 330, GETUTCDATE()),111)
```

OUtput :**2016/05/22**

**Project 2: solution**

instead of using`between` you can use below query for search

```
select * from yourtablename
where (datecolumn>=convert(varchar,dateadd(MI, 330, GETUTCDATE()),111) and 
datecolumn<=convert(varchar,dateadd(MI, 330, GETUTCDATE()),111))
```

try and let me know, damn sure it will work..

Regards:
K

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use (including when you use them in a `CONVERT` call!)

Comment: Yeah but, here am just converting the format alone its not necessity of declare length ,above code will work fine.